# App crashes when calling startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm working on my first Android app, specifically in this case something to help me cook better. I have 2 activities that I'm currently struggling with, my MainActivity.java and whatCanIMake.java. When I start whatCanIMake from MainActivity using `startActivity(intent)`, I'm able to pass objects using parcelables and generally use whatCanIMake. My issue is that I want to be able to pass back a list of everything that I've changed in my whatCanIMake activity. For example: I pass in a list of all the ingredients I currently have, and then whatCanIMake removes the ingredients that a recipe uses. I'd like to pass back the updated list of remaining ingredients.

The problem I'm having is with `startActivityForResult()`. Previously I was successfully able to use `startActivity()`, pass it the intent with the extra parcelables, and Bob's your uncle. When I changed over to `startActivityForResult()`, the new activity fails to launch, as the app crashes before hitting `onCreate()`. Obviously this points to my implementation of `startActivityForResult()`, so I've read basically every stack overflow question related to `startActivityForResult()` and now I'm here!

My code for starting whatCanIMake is below, as well as the `onActivityResult()` and corresponding code inside whatCanIMake.

It's just so odd to me that I can simply change out `startActivityForResult()` for `startActivity()` and the app works again! Thanks for any help in advance.

MainActivity.java:

```
    public void searchRecipe(View view) {
        crossViewVariables.setMakeSort('a');
        Intent recipe = new Intent(this, whatCanIMake.class);
        recipe.putExtra("Pantry",stock);
        recipe.putExtra("Cookbook",activeCookbook);
        recipe.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
        startActivityForResult(recipe,R.integer.search_by_recipe);
        //startActivity(recipe);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {


            case (R.integer.search_by_recipe)://comes from Recipe Search?
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle b = data.getExtras();
                    stock = b.getParcelable("Pantry");
                }
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

                }


            case (R.integer.search_by_ingredient)://comes from Recipe Search?
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle b = data.getExtras();
                    stock = b.getParcelable("Pantry");
                }
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

                }


            case (R.integer.make_recipe)://comes from seeRecipe?
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle b = data.getExtras();
                    stock = b.getParcelable("Pantry");
                }
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            case (R.integer.edit_pantry):
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Bundle b = data.getExtras();
                    stock = b.getParcelable("Pantry");
                }
        }
    }
```

whatCanIMake.java:

```
    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra("Pantry", stock);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,result);
    finish();
```

LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.schre.mememachine, PID: 26721
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                            Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: FORWARD_RESULT_FLAG used while also requesting a result
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1884)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1545)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4283)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4230)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                               at com.example.schre.mememachine.MainActivity.searchRecipe(MainActivity.java:91)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I changed the filtering settings, I found the logs. I'll edit my question to include them! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
recipe.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
```

You do not need it for `startActivityForResult()`, and it's what is causing your crash.

Comment: I just arrived at the same conclusion, I removed it and it worked! I just need to make sure I update the rest of my activity calls in order to fix them all. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, though I don't have such a flag either. What would be the cause?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: If you are getting `FORWARD_RESULT_FLAG used while also requesting a result` -- as shown in the stack trace in the question -- then something added `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` to your `Intent` that you used for `startActivityForResult()`. That is the root cause of the crash in the question.

Comment: After asking a question, the culprit turned out to be something really obscure: I was using random many-digit numbers for activity request codes. It seems that Android doesn't like large numbers for request codes. I've changed the code to a 4 digit integer and it worked instantly. Really weird.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: There is a limit on the request code value when you extend from `FragmentActivity` (e.g., inheriting from `AppCompatActivity`): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#startactivityforresult_4

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
startActivityForResult(recipe,R.integer.search_by_recipe);
```

Try this:

```
startActivityForResult(recipe, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.search_by_recipe));
```

Comment: I'll give it a go, I'll report back. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: didn't seem to help anything