# startActivityForResult crashes while startActivity works

Tags: android, android-activity, start-activity, startactivityforresult

I have an activity that I'm starting:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateItemDetailsActivity.class);
if(storeId != null) {
    intent.putExtra(Identifiers.STORE_ID, storeId);
}
intent.putExtra(Identifiers.ITEM_NAME, name);
intent.putExtra(Identifiers.ITEM_DESCRIPTION, description);
startActivity(intent);
```

This works, but now I need to return data to the original activity, so I change `startActivity` call to:

`startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_ITEM_RESULT);`

(`CREATE_ITEM_RESULT` is just a random integer number 63463657 I made up)

However, my app crashes without neither `onCreate` methods (I've implemented and put a breakpoint in both) being called:

```
Uncaught exception in thread main: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
```

(the code is called in a button click handler, hence `onClick`)

I've seen [App crashes when calling startActivityForResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683084/app-crashes-when-calling-startactivityforresult/45683332) which has the same problem but the accepted answer suggests removing a line, `recipe.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);`, which I don't have.

Why am I getting a crash on `startActivityForResult` while `startActivity` works perfectly?

(My min SDK level is 16, target and compile SDK levels are 27, and I'm running Android 8.1 emulator)

Comment: Try a four digit `int`  value.

Comment: @Barns seriously??? it worked. but why? could you post it as an answer?

Comment: Don't  know. I had issues in the past and when I changed the `int`value to something smaller (like four digits) it worked. I have not checked to see which maximum `int` value I can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If have not seen any documentation on this issue, but try a four digit `int` value should get rid of the error.

I have read Google docs for `startActivityForResult` and I have not found any reference to a maximum `int` size. Even the code documentation states:

> @param requestCode If >= 0, this code will be returned in the
>   onActivityResult() when the activity exists

So, no mention of a maximum `int` value. Odd...

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to @MidasLefko for finding this information:

> RequestCodes can only be a max of 0xffff (65535). So you are probably
>   calling startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); and REQUEST_CODE
>   is greater than 65535.

on this website:

https://code-examples.net/en/q/db5947

Comment: Weird. It would have made much more sense if the method signature had `short` instead of an `int`.

Comment: Found [this link](https://code-examples.net/en/q/db5947) that says that requestcode is limited to 0xffff (65535). Not sure how they know...

Answer (score 2):

In the non-support [Activity class implementation of startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) there is no restriction on the maximum int for requestCode, as long as it is positive. However FragmentActivity (and by extension AppCompatActivity) [overrides this behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#startactivityforresult_4) (documentation):

> void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)
>
> Modifies the standard behavior to allow results to be delivered to fragments. This imposes a restriction
>   that requestCode be <= 0xffff.

In the [source code of FragmentActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/fragment/src/main/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#110) one finds the following helpful comment:

> A hint for the next candidate request index. Request indicies are ints
>   between 0 and 2^16-1 which are encoded into the upper 16 bits of the
>   requestCode for Fragment.startActivityForResult(...) calls. This
>   allows us to dispatch onActivityResult(...) to the appropriate
>   Fragment. Request indicies are allocated by allocateRequestIndex(...).

ints in java are 32 bit, FragmentActivity uses 16 to determine which fragment to send the result to and the other 16 are available for the developer.

Comment: Good find Midas! That was buried deep.

Comment: It makes sense now. It would be even better if it threw an exception indicating the issue, instead of a generic illegal state exception.

Comment: Welcome to Android ;)